# Hidden field Value is Empty on Page load but available on button click event after post back why?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, pageload, hidden-field, buttonclick

I have a Hidden Field with view-state enabled I am storing value in Hidden Field from server side code but the value is empty on page load event after postback, at the same time I am able to access it on button click event.  I have tried with giving same Id,but I am unsuccessful and I am roaming here from quite some time all I found is some saying that make View-state enable and give the same Id with which I am unsuccessful and also I have found that  accessing the hidden field value on "Pre-Init" event with is unsuccessful and got a suggestion saying that try to access it in button click.. is it true??

In my case I have to assign back the value from hidden field to some other control for further operation and here the main problem this Hidden field's count depends on user input so I can't even use client side functionality.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: pre-init is most likely too early as the viewstate hasn't even been loaded yet. Try OnPreLoad (only in page object, not in user control) or OnLoad events. These are good early events in the timeline.

Comment: Thanks mark for your quick reply...:)

Comment: But my problem is,for controls which are re-created on page load values in view state will be binded after page load bt i wanna access them on page load so dat my validation will be true to create these controls before page load is not possible because these depend on user input from a set other dynamically loaded controls which deal with same problem of view state binding.....

Comment: For controls  that are dynamically created you must absolutely create them again in order for them to be in place to receive values. You can do this in OnLoad at the latest. You can swap them out between states by creating them first in OnLoad (or OnPreload) and then if you need to switch them, clear them out and create the new set in OnPreRender. Keep in mind it's an absolute must to have the names exactly the same for each control whenever you create it.